# Collecting tweets

Tags: ruby, mongodb, tweets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I collect real-time tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257418/how-can-i-collect-real-time-tweets)

I want to collect random tweets via Streaming API using RuBY and store them in MongoDB. So I've tried to use this code [Dakatsuka code](https://gist.github.com/656397/ff15fc5396704c91c19aa2ff61cc48414c429ecb)
but it's not working. I'm getting this one protocol.rb:135:in 'sysread' (Errno:ECONNRESET)
What does it means? I'll appreciate your any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using tweetstream gem which uses event-machine . Its pretty simple to use.