# How can I collect real-time tweets?

Tags: ruby

How can I collect real-time tweets using Ruby and store them in MongoDB? Please give me a hint! I've tried to use this code [1](http://gist.github.com/656397) and always get this one and dont know how to deal with it...

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread': 既存の接続はリモート
ホストに強制的に切断されました。 (Errno::ECONNRESET)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2028:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2017:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request'
        from stream.rb:19
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:440:in `start'
        from stream.rb:15
```

Comment: I've tried to use this code https://gist.github.com/656397 but it seems useless coz can't run it

Comment: Can't run it. Why? Please read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), read your question and edit it to provide more detail.

Comment: when I am running it it's gave me this /protocol.rb:135:in 'sysread' (Errno:ECONNRESET) I am just new to ruby and dont know how to deal with this error

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the URL from `http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json` to `https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json`, the streaming API is only available via SSL nowadays (the Gist you linked to is a year old).

Comment: Thanks, but still have problem 
C:/Ruby187?lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in 'sysread':end of file reached (EOFError)

Comment: Why don't you just use a Twitter library instead of doing everything manually? https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream

Comment: I want to store tweets in Mongodb...

Comment: Who's stopping you? Use the gem I linked to above to retrieve the tweets and then use the MongoDB gem similar to the way it's used in the Gist to save them to Mongo.

Comment: which file I should use? There is so many files there

Comment: This is not how programming works. At one point you'll have to learn to solve your own problems. There's a reason this question was closed, it shows a definite lack of effort on your part.